# displaying data from MySQL table java

Tags: mysql

I am displaying data from a table in MySQL. I am displaying the results for a golf competition with the data being displayed in order of highest points to lowest points. I have a column for 1st, 2nd, 3rd etc.
I want that column to display 1, 2 and 3
This is my code on my JSP page to display my table.

```
            <th>Place</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Handicap</th>
            <th>Score</th>
```

```
            <tr>    
                <td><s:property value="place" /></td>
                <td><s:property value="name" /></td>
                <td><s:property value="handicap" /></td>
                <td><s:property value="points" /></td>

            </tr>
            </s:iterator>
```

My data displays fine. I just dont know how to display 1, 2 and 3 in the place column in my table. It displays a zero in each column.

Place             |      Name             |      Handicap         |     Score

0                 |      Joe Bloggs       |          19           |       35

0                 |      Matt Smith       |          16           |       33

0                 |      Mark Kelly       |          17           |       32

Answer (score 0):

Try using a loop with a counter printed out so that each time the counter is incremented, those zeros are replaced with the actual counter value.

for (int i = 0; i < (results.length); ++i) 
{
    //Here use the i value for place provided you sort your sql statement  to  //fetch data in order
}